# Passing an event to a collection in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to trigger behaviour on a collection by triggering an event elsewhere in my app. I am pretty new to backbone, so probably have all my syntax wrong, but this seems like it should work

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atb2t/1/)

```
var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
var Tests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Test,
        events: {
            "testEvent":"testResponce"
        },
        testResponce: function(){
            alert('hello world');
        }
    });



var myTest = new Test();

myTest.trigger('testEvent');
```

Can this be done? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a particular method of your collection using `testEvent` event then you can take this path also. [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/atb2t/8/)

```
var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('testEvent', function() {
            console.log(this.collection);
            this.collection.testResponce();
        });
    }
});
var Tests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Test,
        testResponce: function(){
            alert('hello world');
        }
    });

var myTest = new Test();
var testList = new Tests([myTest]);
myTest.trigger('testEvent');
```

Comment: this does answer the question, so is a worthy recipient of the tick. However, moving forward I actually intend to instantiate a model from the event, so this will create a loop?!

I guess I can create two model classes, one for triggering and one for actual data storage, but it strikes me as overkill to have an entire Backbone model when all I actually want is the trigger method and to not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: If you want to create another model on trigger of `testEvent` event then you can easily create a new model in your `testResponse` method and add it to your collection. There is no looping at all. May be there is a use case and on that basis you have framed this question So please let me know how there is looping involved in it.

Comment: Ahh, I see, sorry, misinterpreted the code. There will be duplicate event bindings though, no?

Comment: @MildFuzz No there won't be duplicate event bindings. Every model is listening to an event `testEvent` and this event gets triggered on the model itself. In the event handler, its upto you what you want to do. In this case, we are calling a method of collection which is perfectly fine. In this case, we have defined an anonymous method as the event handler. `testResponce` is just an another method not an event handler and is called from the anonymous event handler. May be you can explain me How are you seeing a duplicate event binding so that I can answer your query better.

Comment: So each model defined will have an event binding. This works fine, but is unnecessary. All I really want to go is have an event get passed to the controller WITHOUT polluting the global namespace. Only one binding should be required.

Comment: So do you want to trigger an event on collection object and don't want to propagate it through your model, you can do this `myTest.collection.trigger('testEvent');` Check demo here http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/atb2t/10/

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking the binding is still attached to the model, and will thus be attached to all models created ising Bb.Controller.add()?

Comment: In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/atb2t/10/ there is no binding on model, however there is binding on collection and which is you want. There is already a collection object associated with each model and we are just triggering an event on collection. There is only one event binding now and that is only on collection. No binding is there on models.

Answer (score 1):

The event that you are triggering will have to be caught inside the model.

If you want to catch an event inside collection you can use **Backbone.on** and **Backbone.trigger** OR **collection.on** and **collection.trigger**

Please check the fiddle below for an example

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atb2t/2/)

```
var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Tests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Test,
    initialize: function () {
        Backbone.on('testEvent', function () {
            alert('event handled in collection');
        });
    }
});


var myCollection = new Tests();
var myTest = new Test();

Backbone.trigger('testEvent');
```

**UPDATE**

Collection has an [initialize method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor) which you can use to register events on. Later you can trigger these events from their instances.

Other way as [NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/null) suggested is to do it like below.

```
var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Tests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Test,
    initialize: function () {
        this.on('testEvent', function () {
            alert('event handled in collection');
        });
    }
});


var myCollection = new Tests();
var myTest = new Test();

myCollection.trigger('testEvent');
```

Comment: I wouldn't sugest to route the events over the global namespace. Use `this.on` and `this.trigger` where this refers to an instance of `Backbone.Collection`